# Why perl script freezes my server?

Tags: linux, perl

I cannot make my perl-script run stable on the server.
Here is the problem:

When the script is accessed more than 5 times a second, the server freezes.
And in some time later the server hangs forever.
SSH does not respond and I have to reload the server.

I'm using Apache with mod_perl.

The script is hosted on Virtual Dedicated Server under Ubuntu.
I'm operating it through SSH.

This is the server configuration:

- CPU: 400 MHz
- RAM: 256 MB

Maximal execution time of the script is 200 milliseconds.

I have monitored server load with "top" utility.
It does not display any problems, this is the CPU statistics during load of 5 scripts per second.

> Cpu(s): 12.1%us,  0.6%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
>   87.2%st

What options do I have to make the script work without problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I have already found the answer.
There was not enough memory to run it.
Upgrading memory twice resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is on line 58. Look around there.

But seriously, without any clue about the function or code, how do you expect an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the script is called again before it finished - maybe the second instance has no access to called resources or something like that. Hard to tell without some code... What is that perl script actually doing?